# End of scan character for Keyboard Wedge scanners?

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm using a L-TRON 4910LR to scan 2D barcodes using the keyboard interface feature.    Does anyone know if there a way to determine when you have reached the end of that scan?

Comment: Typically, keyboard scanners use a carriage return (hex 0x0D) as an end character.

Answer (score 0):

You can select from three types of CR, TAB, CR+LF according to the setting bar code of the [user guide](https://www.l-tron.com/Support/4910LR-151-User-Guide.pdf).